# What's the difference between 'form#myForm' and '#myForm' in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the difference between:

```
$("form#myForm")
```

and

```
$("#myForm")
```

when it comes to referencing and/or submitting a form in Jquery? I've seen it done both ways. Is there an important difference?

Comment: `<div id="myForm">` would not match `$("form#myForm")`

Comment: @freedomn-m - So succinctly put! :-)

Comment: The question relates to forms. Assuming it's a form, is there a difference?

Comment: `form#myForm` and `#myForm` are two types of CSS selectors. `form#myForm` is more targeted, meaning it will only grab an element of type `form` with id `myForm` `#myForm` will grab any element with id `myForm`

Comment: jQuery selector strings are based on [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) -- this is a type selector `form` which limits selection to `<form>` elements and which further requires an id of `myForm`. The second selector is an id selector only.

Comment: `id=` must (should) be unique, so any selector with `#` will always find the first matching id=.  Assuming you have a unique ID (which you do...ofc) - by adding `form#myForm` you're **double checking** that it is indeed a `form` and hasn't got mixed up somewhere and you're not trying to `.submit()` an `img`.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Just FWIW, `$("#myForm")` becomes `$(document.getElementById("myForm"))` because of the optimization (so, no `filter("form")`). (`$("form#myForm")` will match both if there really are two `form id="myForm"` elements, like CSS does.) All of which arcana is beside the point, of course. ;-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good call. In the case of `form#myForm` it does *not* do the optimisation of doc.getElById.   Quick test confirms this: https://jsfiddle.net/to9q50ks/2/  and another test for more general `.class #id` selector: https://jsfiddle.net/to9q50ks/3/

Comment: Right. Purely for `#xyz` selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming it's a form, if there a difference?

Yes, there's a slight difference, but only on a page that is incorrectly using duplicate `id` values. `form#myForm` will only match an element of type `form`, even if there's another element with `id="myForm"` earlier in the document. `#myForm` (with jQuery) will match just the first one (although that behavior is not documented and shouldn't be relied upon, it's a by-product of a jQuery optimization; don't use duplicate `id` values at all).

Example:

```js
console.log("#myForm matched: " + $("#myForm")[0].tagName);
console.log("form#myForm matched: " + $("form#myForm")[0].tagName);
```

```html
<!-- DON'T DO THIS, `id` VALUES MUST BE UNIQUE IN THE DOCUMENT -->
<div id="myForm"></div>
<form id="myForm"></form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But again: Don't do that.

The `form#myForm` selector is also more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the `#myForm` selector, but again, it shouldn't matter, because there should only be one matching element.